# What is ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue Enqueue #. Why does it keep increasing

Tags: out-of-memory, activemq-classic, spring-jms, enqueue

I am using ActiveMQ queue and publishing messages to a queue and consuming the published msgs.
I am using spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer to consume messages from the Queue. My queue name is cases-queue. When the DefaultMessageListenerContainer  is running I see in ActiveMQ Console , under Topic -- for ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.cases-queue and ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection --- the Enqueue # keeps one increasing in increments of 10.

Will ActiveMQConnectionFactory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false) help. Sorry I am not so familiar with ActiveMQ.

I am not sure what is the ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.cases-queue . Whats the enqueue #?
Why does the Enqueue # keep increasing in ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.cases-queue?
Why does the Enqueue # keep increasing in ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection? **Can this lead to out of memory on the server?**

I also noticed that for a different queue , ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.data-queue , the Enqueue # does not increase . I am not sure how this queue listener/consumer is implemented though.

Please see the picture below :

[screenshot from jboss fuse activemq console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEA1e.png)

[activemq console Topic -- Advisory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIJd3.png)

Answer (score 1):

These are all notification topics that you can subscribe to in order to observe activity on the broker from your messaging clients.  The enqueue count will increase as notifications are sent to those topics but if you have no consumers subscribed to them the action is essentially a no-op so there isn't anything to be overly concerned about here.

There's plenty of [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message) on what each advisory topic provides in terms of notifications.

Comment: Thank you Tim. My main concern, does the increase in Enqueue # lead to a out of memory either on broker's server or server where the listener code is?

Comment: As said my post , ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.data-queue Enqueue # is always 5, and I know the queue has 5 parallel consumers.
Does it mmean the advisory is somehow configured to display consumer count for this queue. Or no notification is sent to this topic.
Where as ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.cases-queue Enqueue # is displaying something else. 
I am not sure what it is. Can you explain.

Comment: (couldnot edit my comment, so adding a new one) Tim. My main concern, we had out of memory on broker's server, so does it mean increase in Enqueue # leads to a out of memory either on broker's server or on server where the listener code is?
From  [documentation] (https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message) , can you please explain 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue Consumer start & stop messages on a Queue.  
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection Connection start & stop messages. 
What does start and stop a message really mean. And Is it 2 notifications one for start, one for stop.

Comment: As I said, these are Topics and so no data is retained on a Topic the enqueue count increases as notification as sent to show said notification was sent, but nothing is retained as...Topic.